# Android app is crashing on SocketTimeoutException in retrofit Interceptor

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, interceptor, socket-timeout-exception

Following is my offline interceptor code. It crashes in case of low network and throws SocketTimeoutException. How to avoid app from crashing in this case?

```
internal class CacheOfflineInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()
        val offlineCacheDuration = request.header(MAX_STALE_IN_DAYS)
        if (!isOnline && offlineCacheDuration != null) {
            val maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * offlineCacheDuration.toLong()

            request = request.newBuilder()
                    .removeHeader(PRAGMA)
                    .header(CACHE_CONTROL, "private, max-stale=$maxStale")
                    .build()
        }

        try {
            val response = chain.proceed(request)
            return response
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            if (e is IOException) {
                throw e
            } else {
                throw IOException(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting following exception in low network case

```
Fatal Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.110 (port 8888) from /192.168.0.159 (port 49025) after 10000ms
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:185)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:130)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are throwing an `Exception` in `Interceptor` when something fails, which throws that `Exception` all the way upto the `Caller`, in order to avoid crash, you need to handle this `Exception` at some level, either you can suppress it in `interceptor` and log it for reference (or) you can just handle the exception in caller chain.

Comment: The `Interceptor` interface declares the incercept() method with a throwable @Throws(IOException::class), so technically it is trying to satisfy adding the try/catch sentence in the code taking care that only IOException, is supposed that retrofit should handle it internally however a SocketTimeoutException was throw anyway, I have a similar problem but on my case is throwing a java.net.ConnectException exception